# Listen for Wake-on-LAN requests on windows platform

Tags: windows, windows-10, wake-on-lan, sniffing

We would like to search for Wake-on-LAN packet senders within our network from our Windows machines (mostly Windows 10).

The [solution described by Chaos](https://superuser.com/a/870620/545162) applies only to Linux.

Is there also a similar easy solution for this on Windows for the command line, power shell or with a free 3rd party tool?

Background:
Our machines are woken up daily without purpose and we try to search and eliminate the sender.

Answer (score 1):

> **The solution described by Chaos in this question applies only to linux.**

That's not true, search for "netcat for windows"

There are plenty of network sniffers that can also do this job. E.g. Wireshark.